# Possible use of lambdify() with Sympy to take advantage of numerical solvers for three equations and three unknowns

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, solver

I've three real, multivariate equations (three variables) that need to be solved, simultaneously, for numerical results (not symbolic, in this case.) In the past, I've just used SymPy's solve() function which works great for much of what I work on (linear symbolic equations.)

But these three are non-linear. Assume three symbolic expressions e1, e2, and e3 with real, positive variables c1, c2, and c3:

```
c1, c2, c3 = symbols( 'c1,c2,c3', real=True, positive=True )
e1 = f(c1, c2, c3)               # f() is actually too long to write out
e2 = g(c1, c2, c3)               # g() is actually too long to write out
e3 = h(c1, c2, c3)               # h() is actually too long to write out
                                 # .. but see at-bottom for f() for clarity
```

I do not get any errors when attempting the following:

```
solve( [ Eq(e1, -1), Eq(e2, -0.5), Eq(e3, -sqrt(3)/2) ], [ c1, c2, c3 ] )
```

And I happen to know the vicinity of the right answers: c1=3.5472, c2=1.39199, and c3=0.20238 (roughly.)

However, I terminated the solution attempt after waiting a few hours.

I am not sure how to "help" the above solver with the nearby values. (I am a casual user and therefore likely sufficiently ignorant to not know how to find the right documentation, readily, if such exists. I did try and considered asking for help only after a few hours spent there, as well. I won't document all my failed attempts here.)

So I decided that if I were to lambdify the above equations then perhaps I could take advantage of other solvers.

My first inclination was to set up lambdified functions to result in zero, as I imagined the possibility of a reduced set of options, otherwise. So, as follows:

```
f1 = lambdify( (c1,c2,c3), e1 + 1 )
f2 = lambdify( (c1,c2,c3), e2 + 0.5 )
f3 = lambdify( (c1,c2,c3), e3 + sqrt(3)/2 )
```

And when I plug in my approximate values for c1, c2, and c3, I do get near-zero outputs from f1, f2, and f3. Which is good. It means I did at least manage to use lambdify (for the first time) in a way that worked as I expected it might.

However, now I'm stuck with which way to head from here.

I do have a lot of failed results I could document. But, looking back over them, they are entirely about my ignorance and probably not particularly helpful here. Noise and very little signal in there, I think.

There is one and only one possible solution and all three will converge on zero at the same time. So this isn't exactly a simulated annealing kind of problem (though amenable to it, I suppose.) I had fully expected SymPy's solve() to deal with this rather quickly, but now I suspect that it is spinning its wheels taking symbolic derivatives. (Of course, I'm not sure.) But this is why I was thinking about porting over these expressions into a more numerical side of things in hopes of a solver that will work with numerical differences rather than symbolic derivatives.

What's the right approach here? I'm lost. I think the answer should be more about me learning something new about syntax that I'm lacking, for now. But bear in mind that e1, e2, and e3 are not linear combinations of c1, c2, and c3. They involve a variety of integer powers, square roots, cube roots, and combinations of various products of any two or three of them, as well.

That's it. I'm hoping for a nudge in the right direction if not an outright "here's how" answer.

**Note:** e1, e2, and e3 are below on separate lines for anyone caring what these things look like:

```
-(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))/(3*(sqrt(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**(1/3)) - (sqrt(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**(1/3)/3 - (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(3*c1*c2*c3)
((c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) - (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(3*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))*re(1/((-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**(1/3))) + sqrt(3)*((cos(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2 + sin(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)**2*Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/4)**(1/6)*sin(atan2(sin(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2, cos(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))/3)/6 + ((cos(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2 + sin(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)**2*Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/4)**(1/6)*cos(atan2(sin(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2, cos(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))/3)/6 - (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(3*c1*c2*c3)
((c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) - (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(3*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))*im(1/((-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**(1/3))) + ((cos(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2 + sin(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)**2*Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/4)**(1/6)*sin(atan2(sin(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2, cos(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))/3)/6 - sqrt(3)*((cos(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2 + sin(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)**2*Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/4)**(1/6)*cos(atan2(sin(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2, cos(atan2(0, -4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2)/2)*sqrt(Abs(-4*(-3*(c2 + 3*c3)/(c1*c2*c3) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**2/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2))**3 + (27/(c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + 2*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))**2))/2 + 27/(2*c1*c2*c3) - 9*(c2 + 3*c3)*(2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)/(2*c1**2*c2**2*c3**2) + (2*c1*c3 + 2*c2*c3)**3/(c1**3*c2**3*c3**3))/3)/6
```

Comment: Have you tried [`nsolve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve)? What about one of scipy's root finding functions?

Comment: @jared Yes, I did. But that doesn't mean I used them correctly. I tried to follow what I understood of the docs. I could attempt to write down all my failures above. But I fear it would serve to distract more than help. But yes. I have tried not only nsolve but quite a few other approaches, including scanning around for an existing simulated annealing approach (which, by the way, I'm now writing code so that I can get a result assuming no one answers here, today. It's not complicated to write, luckily.)

Comment: I would take a step back here and consider where you got these expressions from. My guess is that you called `roots` on some polynomial but probably it would be better not to do that especially if the end goal is a numerical solution: it would be easier to work with the polynomial itself rather than an expression for its roots.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin It's a solution to a 3rd order Butterworth polynomial, but where there are six electronic components that make up the coefficients of the 3rd order form. Three of those components are assigned the value of 1, though. The Butterworth has three roots, one real and a conjugate pair. The requirement is to find the relative ratio of the remaining three components with respect to the other three (valued 1). That's done by taking the real root for one equation, the real and imaginary of one of the conjugate pair for the other two. This solves out for a practical system to design.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin So I'm not sure how to follow your advice. Though I wouldn't mind learning a new way of seeing things.

Comment: I don't fully understand your description from the comment above but I would not be surprised if there is a better way than using `roots`. Feel free to ask a new question where you show what the polynomial is and explain how to get from the polynomial to the equations that you are trying to solve above.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin When I get a moment to do it some justice (perhaps in a day or two?) I'll see if I can compose it well. And thanks for encouraging me to learn further. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sympy also exposes `nsolve`, which can be used to numerically solve a system of linear (or nonlinear) equation. All you have to do is:

```py
nsolve([e1, e2, e3], [c1, c2, c3], [3.5472, 1.39199, 0.20238])
```

This function lambdifies the expressions and uses mpmath's `findroot`. It's very handy if you happen to know a good initial guess.

Since you have 3 equations, you could also use [SymPy Plotting Backend's `plot3d_implicit`](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/plot_functions/functions_3d.html#spb.plot_functions.functions_3d.plot3d_implicit) to find a good initial guess:

```py
from spb import *
plot3d_implicit(e1, e2, e3, (c1, -5, 5), (c2, -5, 5), (c3, -5, 5), backend=KB, n=150)
```

Anyway, without knowing the exact expressions for `e2, e3`, this is all I can suggest.

Comment: I need to check out what you are writing (I know the semantics of what I want, but my syntax skills are minimal and I learn by doing, right now.)  But for the moment, e2 and e3 look very similar except perhaps about twice as long. But nothing new in terms of non-linear combinations. I'll paste them in, just in case it matters.

Comment: Added them. It's ugly. ;)

Comment: Okay. That's good. I was stuck on trying the lambdas, which I'd placed into an array so that they could be callable. Just could not get that working with nsolve. But what you write is what I should have just tried and didn't. Too zeroed in, I guess. What I need to use is e1+1, e2+0.5, and e3+sqrt(3)/2 instead of what you write. But that's it. Thanks! Result here is 3.54681827688408, 1.39264678170264, 0.202451072765786. And that's where I wanted to be. :)

Comment: Hmm. Just tried the plot3d_implicit. I first performed the install for the entire backend per the site you linked. That all seemed to run fine. But when using Python per their testing instructions I get *"Unable to import Axes3D. This may be due to multiple versions of Matplotlib being installed (e.g. as a system package and as a pip package). As a result, the 3D projection is not available."*. And there it stops. I also tried to go straight into Sagemath where I already have imported SymPy and it says it does not recognize `spb` as a module, at all. Even after installing the backend.

Comment: That said, [this Sympy page](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html) on plotting mentions plot3d and if I `plot3d?` to get info, I get good info. But that site does NOT mention plot3d_implicit and if I try `plot3d_implicit?` then it says that it wasn't found. So consistent with that page, the feature appears to be hidden/absent at this time in my WSL UBUNTU. I suppose I could ask this as a second question. But if you have a quick thought, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `plot3d_implicit` is a function of [SymPy Plotting Backend](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is a different module, which extends SymPy's limited plotting capabilities. Regarding your problems about the installation, are you sure you are not mixing "environments"? Btw, I never tried WSL, so maybe that is causing issues?

Comment: I completely installed the backend and it went just as they explained it would. I used the `[all]` to grab up everything, though. Rebooted Ubuntu from start, fired up Sagemath, and no-go on the import. Said it doesn't recognize the module... at all. So I will form up another question, I guess. Thanks, anyway, for taking another moment here. Appreciated.